# Is it possible to combine FFImageLoading with Mr.Gestures?

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading, mr.gestures

Is it possible to combine FFImageLoading with Mr.Gestures? If so how would that be possible?

Its being mentioned in this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32956/mr-gestures-handles-all-touch-gestures/p8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you can just use a Layout from MrGestures, such as Grid, and within, put your image.

```
<mr:Grid HeightRequest="300"
         Padding="0"
            DownCommand="{Binding DownCommand}"
            UpCommand="{Binding UpCommand}"
            TappingCommand="{Binding TappingCommand}"
            TappedCommand="{Binding TappedCommand}"
            DoubleTappedCommand="{Binding DoubleTappedCommand}"
            LongPressingCommand="{Binding LongPressingCommand}"
            LongPressedCommand="{Binding LongPressedCommand}"
            PanningCommand="{Binding PanningCommand}"
            PannedCommand="{Binding PannedCommand}"
            SwipedCommand="{Binding SwipedCommand}"
            PinchingCommand="{Binding PinchingCommand}"
            PinchedCommand="{Binding PinchedCommand}"
            RotatingCommand="{Binding RotatingCommand}"
            RotatedCommand="{Binding RotatedCommand}"
            >
 <ffimageloading:CachedImage WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}">
        </ffimageloading:CachedImage>

</Grid>
```

Comment: It worked. It can be noted I used `MR.Gestures.ContentView`